# Is Slice<Results> still lazy loaded in Realm?

Tags: arrays, swift, realm

I'm trying to limit the results of my Realm query. If I have a million records and I call Swift `prefix` function, does it touch all million records?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
let objects = realm.objects(BookRealmObject.self)
    .sorted(byKeyPath: "createdAt", ascending: false)

let items: [BookType] = {
    guard let limit = request.limit, limit > 0 else {
        return objects.map { Book(from: $0) }
    }

    return objects.prefix(limit).map { Book(from: $0) }
}()
```

The type returned from `prefix` is `Slice<Results<Element>>`. Whether a limit is requested by the caller or not, I need to convert it to a plain object to pass to different threads.

Is this the proper way to handle this, or is there a more optimized, concise way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can find in [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#limiting-results):

> Since queries in Realm are lazy, performing this sort of paginating behavior isn’t necessary at all, as Realm will only load objects from the results of the query once they are explicitly accessed.

So, when you get the prefix of objects it still should be lazy, but when you access objects using `map` you lose the lazy feature.